# how to set Android Camera Preview in green color?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

i want to open my camera in myActivity with green color, i read so much for it, to configure like this,but no any solution,

now i used like following :

```
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    params.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
```

it set camera preview in blue color,but no any parameter to set camera preview in green color, so any other way are possible to change camera preview in green color ?

Comment: You can send the camera output to a SurfaceTexture and render it with GLES.  This requires a bunch of code but makes it easy to do a wide range of effects.  See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika); demo at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg .

Comment: you give me any simple example of transparent image on OpenGL or it may work on it ?

Comment: In Grafika, see the "hardware scaler exerciser".  The textures used a partially transparent, which you can see when they overlap.